# Create concurrent thread/promise in grails

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy, promise, task

I have an action in my grails application and I want to start an asynchronous method when the action is called. I am trying use promises to do that, but seems that task1 runs syschronously. Someone know how I can make this task1 run asyncrhonously (concurrently) doing its processing at the same time of action collector?

```
def collector(){

    try{

        Promise task1 = task {
            println "task1 - starting"
            console() //call another method
            println "task1 - ending"
        }

        //do something
        ...
    }catch(){
       ....
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Grails 3:

```
import grails.async.Promise
import static grails.async.Promises.task

Promise p = task {
    // do stuff
}
p.onError { Exception err ->
    log.error( "Error during task $err" )
}
p.onComplete {
    log.info "Task completed"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three ways running a code fragment asyncrhonously

**A**. use Thread

```
def mytask={println "3.hello"}
println "1.begin"
 new Thread( {
         mytask();
    }).start() 
println "2.end"
```

the output:

> 1.begin
>
> 2.end
>
> 3.hello

**B**. use Events

```
 import grails.events.Events
 
 @Consumer    
 class Game  implements Events{
    @Selector("play")
    def doPlay(Object msg) {
       println msg.toString()
    }
}

def gameScenarioService 

//send event, will call doPlay method asyncrhonously
notify ( "play", "First Play" )
```

**C**. use [GPars](http://www.gpars.org/)

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.gpars', module='gpars', version='1.2.1')

import groovyx.gpars.actor.DefaultActor
 

class CustomActor extends DefaultActor {
    @Override protected void act() {
        loop {
            react {
                println it
            }
        }
    }
}
println "begin"
def console=new CustomActor()
console.start()

//trigger to react
console.send('Message')
println "end"

sleep(100) {
    // wait Message
}
```

the output:

> begin
>
> end
>
> Message

Comment: When I call new Thread( { mytask(); }).start() first mytask() is entirely processed and only after the processing of my parent thread continue. I want that both (caller method of thread and the thread) run at same time.

Comment: They _do_ parallel, but to see the effect, you must execute a time consuming task, try a for-loop 10000 times and you will see